# GA Skill for checked in guests

Tags: actions-on-google

We are building a GA skill which lets hotel guests use room service using GA voice.

When a user interacts with GA, the information is sent to my system, which then sends the alerts to hotel staff to do the room service tasks like change bed sheets, repair AC, pick up laundry or even book a table in the same hotel (Not in form of transaction).

My skill got rejected because GA testing team consider in a regular B2C skill where anyone will be able to use the skill (In our case only checked in guest can use the skill) and consider every action as a transaction and found it misleading.

Is there any channel where we can describe the business case in details before submitting the skill?

Answer (score 0):

You can include in the testing instructions information about the environment and how you expect it to work. Feel free to be as detailed as possible to help them understand.

It sounds like you need to use account linking, so you needed to provide a test account for them as well. This is another opportunity to explain what this test account emulates and how you see it being used.

Finally, since you've been rejected, you can reply to that message to further explain why you don't need to use transactions and how the connection is intended to work. Again - be as detailed as possible. But also be willing to listen and try to understand where they are coming from.